# smtp.js only works locally

Tags: javascript, smtp

I am trying to send emails through javascript with smtp.js. If I open my website locally everything works fine, but if i host it on my domain it just stops working. How can I make it work?

```
  function sendEmail() {
    Email.send({
      SecureToken: "5b51f40c-7d97-46db-a4d7-055bc8384828",
      To: "contact@jayden.hu",
      From: document.getElementById("input2").value,
      Subject: "Contact",
      Body:
        "Name: " +
        document.getElementById("input1").value +
        "<br> E-mail: " +
        document.getElementById("input2").value +
        "<br> Message: " +
        document.getElementById("input3").value,
    }).then((message) => alert(message, type));
  }
```

Error I get:

```
smtp.js:2 POST https://smtpjs.com/v3/smtpjs.aspx? net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED
ajaxPost    @   smtp.js:2
(anonymous) @   smtp.js:2
send    @   smtp.js:2
sendEmail   @   (index):185
onsubmit    @   (index):139
smtp.js:2 POST https://smtpjs.com/v3/smtpjs.aspx? net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED
ajaxPost    @   smtp.js:2
(anonymous) @   smtp.js:2
send    @   smtp.js:2
sendEmail   @   (index):185
onsubmit    @   (index):139
```